# pgpool can't create database

Tags: database, postgresql, pgpool

I have started the `pgpool` using the command

```
sudo pgpool -n &
```

it started giving the following message on the terminal:

> 2012-05-04 10:54:29 LOG:   pid 4109: pgpool-II successfully started. version 2.3.2.1 (tomiteboshi)

But when I try to run the following command:

```
createdb -p 9999 bench_replication
```

I get the following error message:

> createdb: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory.
>   Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.9999"?

When I change the port from 9999 to 5432, a database `bench_replication` is  created on the local node only, not on slave nodes. But, tutorial say to mention port 9999 in this command in order to create database `bench_replication` on all slave nodes through `pgpool`.

To confirm whether `pgpool` is really running or not, I stop the `pgpool` using command

```
2012-05-04 10:58:50 LOG:   pid 4109: received smart shutdown request
stop request sent to pgpool. waiting for termination...done.
[1]+  Done                    sudo -A pgpool -n
```

which confirms the `pgpool` was actually running. What am I doing wrong? I have changed all my `pgpool` configuration file as mentioned in the standard tutorials on net.

Answer (score 5):

Try this command :

```
createdb -p 9999 -h 127.0.0.1 bench_replication
```

By default PostgreSQL try to use the socket.

Comment: Four years later and still working! It should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

Late response but useful for future generations:

When you run

```
createdb -p 9999 bench_replication
```

under root, this generates the following error in log:

> no pg_hba.conf entry for host "12.34.56.78", user "root", database
>   "postgres", SSL off

This means you should explicit mention username just like this:

```
createdb -U postgres -p 9999 bench_replication
```

Then you will get another error:

> no pg_hba.conf entry for host "12.34.56.78", user "postgres", database
>   "postgres", SSL off

So you were blocked by second node on HBA level. 
In this case either you should allow on second node access from first (in pg_hba.conf):
host    all             postgres          12.34.56.77               trust
or you should set password:
createdb -U postgres -p 9999 bench_replication -W SoMeP4Ssw0rD

---

If this is not clear enough - just check for your logs.